# Cannot install ElasticSearch on circleci due to permission errors

Tags: python-3.x, circleci

I have this error on elasticsearch:

```
Collecting aws-requests-auth
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/ba/e1601d0508b4150f8fe503f681079a7c9a17f7aa44e0d5cc42b9e3abdb8e/aws-requests-auth-0.4.2.tar.gz
Collecting boto3
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/c4/d777bd125e6ef304ef52aa7c442a39b33b491922c6495ebd6663322508e4/boto3-1.10.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (128kB)

     |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 44.0MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from elasticsearch==6.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.25.6)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=0.14.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from aws-requests-auth->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.22.0)
Collecting s3transfer<0.3.0,>=0.2.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/16/8a/1fc3dba0c4923c2a76e1ff0d52b305c44606da63f718d14d3231e21c51b0/s3transfer-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (70kB)

     |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 20.4MB/s 
Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/94/7179c3832a6d45b266ddb2aac329e101367fbdb11f425f13771d27f225bb/jmespath-0.9.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting botocore<1.14.0,>=1.13.10
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/69/78a1ee8d8c302c4cee6b088f2d166686b78135a86a65c5d2207b2964e438/botocore-1.13.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.3MB)

     |████████████████████████████████| 5.4MB 58.9MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=0.14.0->aws-requests-auth->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=0.14.0->aws-requests-auth->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=0.14.0->aws-requests-auth->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (2019.9.11)
Collecting python-dateutil<2.8.1,>=2.1; python_version >= "2.7"
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (226kB)

     |████████████████████████████████| 235kB 84.0MB/s 
Collecting docutils<0.16,>=0.10
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/cd/a6aa959dca619918ccb55023b4cb151949c64d4d5d55b3f4ffd7eee0c6e8/docutils-0.15.2-py3-none-any.whl (547kB)

     |████████████████████████████████| 552kB 62.4MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil<2.8.1,>=2.1; python_version >= "2.7"->botocore<1.14.0,>=1.13.10->boto3->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (1.12.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: aws-requests-auth
  Building wheel for aws-requests-auth (setup.py) ... - done
  Created wheel for aws-requests-auth: filename=aws_requests_auth-0.4.2-cp36-none-any.whl size=6831 sha256=12a613fe4a630e82d7909be436f3a5ae758b58a8475a4d4fadd24dcca3a12bce
  Stored in directory: /home/circleci/.cache/pip/wheels/3b/d7/e6/3bb2668c259b234ec78b7353f9063104dc449c1c89fc8e27f8
Successfully built aws-requests-auth
Installing collected packages: elasticsearch, aws-requests-auth, jmespath, python-dateutil, docutils, botocore, s3transfer, boto3
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch-6.3.0.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

But I'm not sure why I'm getting the error. I am trying to use a virtualenv to install... shouldn't this get around the permission error?

```
version: 2
defaults: &defaults
  working_directory: ~/app/
  docker:
    - image: circleci/python:3.6
jobs:
  build_dataloader:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Setup virtualenv
          command: |
            virtualenv env
            source env/bin/activate
      - run:
          name: Install requirements
          command: |
            cd dataloader
            pip install -r requirements.txt
  dataloader_tests:
    <<: *defaults
    parallelism: 2
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Running dataloader tests
          command: |
            cd ~/app/dataloader
            python3 -m unittest discover tests/unit/
      - store_artifacts:
          path: test-reports/
          destination: app_tests
  build_extract:
    <<: *defaults
    working_directory: ~/app/extract
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: ls -a
      - run:
          name: Setup virtualenv
          command: |
            virtualenv env
            source env/bin/activate
      - run:
          name: Install requirements
          command: |
            pip install -r requirements.txt
  extract_tests:
    <<: *defaults
    parallelism: 2
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Running extract tests
          command: |
            cd extract
            python3 -m unittest discover tests/unit/
      - store_artifacts:
          path: test-reports/
          destination: app_tests

workflows:
  version: 2
  run_tests:
    jobs:
      - build_dataloader
      - dataloader_tests:
          requires:
            - build_dataloader
      - build_extract
      - extract_tests:
          requires:
            - build_extract
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing a little bit here, but the error indicates that it's not installing to your virtualenv, it's installing to your base interpreter. This tells me that your `source env/bin/activate` is not applying to other steps (e.g. the run which contains `pip install`).  So your options would be to include everything in the same `run` step as the `source` or put the `source` command in every `run` step.

Comment: Do the steps not carry over to other steps?